Mathematical Constant E
I'm trying to write the formula that solves for e in C#.
e = 1 + (1 / 1!) + (1 / 2!) + (1 / 3!) + ...
I have written this code to solve the problem for the "n!" Fractional numbers.
//n! = n * (n - 1)*(n - 2)*...* 1
//5! = 5 * (5 - 1)*(5 - 2)*(5 - 3)*(5 - 4)*(5 - 5)
//5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 0
//5! = 120

int num = A;
while (num > 0)
{
   A = num;
   for (int i = A - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
      A *= i;
   }
   Console.WriteLine($"Fractorial of {A}! = {num}\n");
   num--;
}

With the n! variable discovered: I'm confused about how to implement it into the e = 1 + (1/n!) + (1/n!++)
This answer doesn't use the System.Math.E function.

instead of a while loop, rewrite your existing method to be recursive.  you will quickly see how to modify the new method to get the end result you desire.

Kevin. Thanks for the input. Can you give me an example of recursive? I'm having a hard time imagining recursive helping or not.

Tip: If you want even more digits than fits into a long consider using the BigInteger type instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-8.0

As Dmitry points out, recursion isn't required.  I just always default to it for recursive math functions.  I find it easier to see the patterns.

@PoulBak When I replace the 'long' with 'BigInteger,' I encounter this error in the Visual Studio IDE [Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'BigInteger']. I think, in theory, BigInteger should work here. Unless BigInteger is used to enlarge the values on the left side of the decimal place.

Yes, BigInteger is an integer, so to use it, you must push the e value all the way to the left, so it becomes an int too. I just mentioned it as a fun experiment for you.

Here's easy code snippet with explanations:
// How many elements to sum - 
// the more elements will be used to determine
// e, the greater precision.
var precision = 50;

// We use Enumerable.Range(1, precision)
// to generate sequence 1, 2, 3, ...
// Then for each element we calculate 1 / x!,
// Additionally forcing floating point calculations
// by 1M. This is the main formulae.

var e = 1 + Enumerable.Range(1, precision)
    .Select(x => 1M / Factorial(x))
    .Sum();

// Print number
Console.WriteLine(e);

// Utility method, that recursively 
// caluclates factorial.
long Factorial(long number) => number > 1
    ? number * Factorial(number - 1)
    : 1;


Michal Turczyn, I appreciate your great insight. I was able to get the following number for E 2.718281828459045~~2210322495454
While Dmitry got the following for E 2.718281828459045~~5
Also, Poul Bak got for E 2.718281828459045~~2353602874713527
Also, Microsoft Visual Studio IDE 2022 has gotten
2.718281828459045~~1
I'm grateful for everyone's input.

You don't need a recursion in this particular case.
The computation can be done in a single loop as follows:
double e = 1;   // The result
long n = 1;     // Let's start from 1
long nFac = n;  // n!
while (nFac < long.MaxValue / n) // Iterate while we can
                                 // (while the long type can fit a factorial)
{
    nFac *= n;       // New factorial
    e += 1.0 / nFac; // Add (1/n!)
    n++;             // Next
}
Console.WriteLine($"e = {e}");

dotnetfiddle

This doesn't perform the math as he's outlined.  But it definitely works and will give a good approximation of 'e'

When I run that method compared to the System.Math.E function, I get your output of "2.7182818284590455, " which is the 16th decimal place and gives us the extra value of .000000000005. We might have discovered a more accurate value than the pre-baked function Microsoft gave us and what the World Wide Web can share from a quick query in the Bing search engine.

@H.Cahill: Windows calculator (Scientific) gives: 2,7182818284590452353602874713527.

Recursive means it calls itself...
public int factorial(int upperLimit) {
  if(upperLimit >= 3) { 
    return upperLimit * factorial(upperLimit - 1); 
  }
  else {
    return upperLimit; 
  }
}

This function calls itself until the parameter reaches 3.  You use 3 because 1! is 1 and multiplying by 1 = the original value, so you don't need this iteration.  2! is 2, but you still need to multiply the original by 2 to get the correct answer.
If you walk it through logically when upperLimit is 5 this is what happens:

factorial is called with upperLimit 5 -- original
factorial is
called with upperLimit 4
factorial is called with upperLimit 3
factorial is called with upperLimit 2


2 is returned
3*2 is returned
4*(3*2) is returned
5*(4*(3*2)) is returned


4 calls, 4 returns.
From here you should be able to see how to modify this function to the one that gets 'e' per your other formula.  Note: you need to change the return type because 'e' is not an int (and for large values of upperLimit you may also need different return type)

That's a masterfully crafted illustration of "Recursive" in C#. I'll remember it in my future programming adventures.
